# Go pkg/mod vs pkg/windowsamd_64 on go build

Tags: go, build, go-modules, gopath

I am beginner in go and facing difficulty in understanding **go/pkg** folder.As suggested by documentation it contains  pkg/mod and pkg/windowsamd_64. pkg/windowsamd_64 for storing compiled files. What happens if I have a file importing some external github modules and  do go build on that.

- Will it go first to pkg/mod (but modules are compiled in
  pkg/windowsamd_64) to search for external modules
- Will it go first to pkg/windowsamd_64 (then what will be use of
  pkg/mod) to search for modules
- Will it go to {gopath}/src and do something from there
- pkg/mod is just a folder ,why do we call it cache as it will keep on
  filling or better when does it populate?

Answer (score 1):

The `go` command has two different modes of locating packages: module mode (introduced in Go 1.11) and `GOPATH` mode (much older). Module mode is the default as of Go 1.16, and if you are new to Go you will probably want to work exclusively in that mode. (There isn't much point to working in `GOPATH` mode unless you have a large legacy codebase that requires it.)

`pkg/mod` stores cached source code for use in module mode. The source code for a given version of a module is downloaded automatically when you build a package from that module (for example, as a dependency of some other package).

`GOPATH/src` stores source code for use in `GOPATH` mode. You can also choose to work in that directory in module mode, but that's a completely optional/aesthetic choice and shouldn't change the behavior of anything in module mode.

`pkg/windows_amd64` stores installed packages in `GOPATH` mode. However, installed packages aren't very useful anyway because Go has a separate build cache (even in `GOPATH` mode). So you can mostly ignore `pkg/windows_amd64` completely.